# Сhange start day of the week for LabelMaker (composeml libraries)

Tags: python

I am trying to create labels for a customer and a week period.
I need `labeling_function` to calculate the sale amount from Monday inclusive to Monday not inclusive.
But now it's calculating from Sunday to Sunday.
How to change start day of the week for `LabelMaker`

```
def total_spent(df):
    total = df['amount'].sum()
    return total

label_maker = cp.LabelMaker(
    target_entity="customer_id",
    time_index="transaction_time",
    labeling_function=total_spent,
    window_size="W",
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the question. You can get the weekly frequency on Mondays by setting the window size to `W-MON`. I'll go through a quick example with this data.

```py
import pandas as pd

records = []
for time in  pd.date_range(start='2020-11-16', periods=15, freq='d'):
    record = {'transaction_time': time, 'day_name': time.day_name()}
    records.append(record)

df = pd.DataFrame(records).assign(customer_id=0)
```

```
transaction_time   day_name  customer_id
      2020-11-16     Monday            0
      2020-11-17    Tuesday            0
      2020-11-18  Wednesday            0
      2020-11-19   Thursday            0
      2020-11-20     Friday            0
      2020-11-21   Saturday            0
      2020-11-22     Sunday            0
      2020-11-23     Monday            0
      2020-11-24    Tuesday            0
      2020-11-25  Wednesday            0
      2020-11-26   Thursday            0
      2020-11-27     Friday            0
      2020-11-28   Saturday            0
      2020-11-29     Sunday            0
      2020-11-30     Monday            0
```

In the label maker, I set the window size to `W-MON`. This is an offset alias for a weekly frequency on Mondays. The window size also supports many other [offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html?highlight=alias#offset-aliases) from pandas.

```py
import composeml as cp

lm = cp.LabelMaker(
    target_entity='customer_id',
    time_index='transaction_time',
    window_size='W-MON',
)
```

Let's inspect the data slices generated by the label maker. You should get a weekly frequency on Mondays.

```py
slices = lm.slice(df, -1)
next(slices)
```

```
                   day_name  customer_id
transaction_time                        
2020-11-16           Monday            0
2020-11-17          Tuesday            0
2020-11-18        Wednesday            0
2020-11-19         Thursday            0
2020-11-20           Friday            0
2020-11-21         Saturday            0
2020-11-22           Sunday            0
```

```py
next(slices)
```

```
                   day_name  customer_id
transaction_time                        
2020-11-23           Monday            0
2020-11-24          Tuesday            0
2020-11-25        Wednesday            0
2020-11-26         Thursday            0
2020-11-27           Friday            0
2020-11-28         Saturday            0
2020-11-29           Sunday            0
```